# Java: abstract or generic list that all derived classes must implement

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, arraylist, collections

I am making a component-based system for a game engine in Java.

I have different system classes to take care of different things, e.g., PhysicsSystem, RenderSystem, EditorSystem and so on. All classes inherits from BaseSystem, which in turn implements an interface ISystem.

I would like all of my system classes to have an ArrayList, but the type in each of them may differ, meaning that the RenderSystem might have a list of RenderComponents, while the PhysicsSystem has a list of PhysicsBodyComponents.

Is it possible to define a generic or abstract list in either the BaseSystem class or the ISystem interface that all the derived classes then implements? I have little experience with generics, so I am a bit confused by this.

This is my current code. As you can see, I created a second list for the derived class, which is kind of a waste.

```
interface ISystem
{
    boolean AddToSystem(Component c);
}

abstract class BaseSystem implements ISystem
{
    // can I make this list generic, so it can store any type in derived classes?
    // e.g., Component, IRenderable, IPhysics, etc.
    protected List<Component> _componentList;
}

class RenderSystem extends BaseSystem
{

    //  need to make a second list that stores the specific render components
    List<IRenderable> _renderList = new ArrayList<IRenderable>();

    void Update()
    {
        for (IRenderable r : _renderList)
            r.Render(); // this code is specific to the IRenderable components
    }

    @Override
    public boolean AddToSystem(Component c)
    {
        boolean succesfullyAdded = false;

        if (c instanceof IRenderable)
        {
            succesfullyAdded = true;
            _renderList.add((IRenderable) c);

        } else
            throw new RuntimeException("ERROR - " + c.Name() + " doesn't implement IRenderable interface!");

        return succesfullyAdded;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
private static abstract class AbstractClass<T> {

    final List<T> objects = new ArrayList<T>();
}

private static class ComponentHolder extends AbstractClass<Component> {

    public void add(final Component c) {
        objects.add(c);
    }

    public Component getComponent(final int index) {
        return objects.get(index);
    }
}
```

In your example, it would be something like this:

```
abstract class BaseSystem<T> implements ISystem
{
    protected List<T> _componentList = new ArrayList<T>();
}

class RenderSystem extends BaseSystem<IRenderable>
{
    void Update()
    {
        for (IRenderable r : _componentList)
            r.Render(); // this code is specific to the IRenderable components
    }

    @Override
    public boolean AddToSystem(Component c)
    {
        boolean succesfullyAdded = false;

        if (c instanceof IRenderable)
        {
            succesfullyAdded = true;
            _componentList.add((IRenderable) c);

        } else
            throw new RuntimeException("ERROR - " + c.Name() + " doesn't implement IRenderable interface!");

        return succesfullyAdded;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work :) Being very inexperienced with generic types, would you care to explain why/how this works? More specifically, how it goes from `<T>` in `BaseSystem` to `<IRenderable>` in `RenderSystem`? Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am not sure I really understand how this `<T>` thing works :\

Comment: @Wikzo Take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) it's well explained. In short `<T>` does not really exist, it's replaced by the class/interface you used in `... extends BaseSystem<class/interface>` at runtime

Comment: @Wizkzo you should also have a look at [Generics, Inheritance and Subtypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html), but if you want to understand the whole generics mechanism of Java, you should walk through all the [Generics lessons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at that :)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, assuming that all your components implement `IComponent` use something like this:

```
interface ISystem<ComponentType extends IComponent> {
   public boolean AddToSystem(ComponentType c);
}
```

If you do not want to have a hard type dependency, you can remove the `extends IComponent`, but it will make handling lists of systems harder.

Comment: You should add class declaration too in your answer E.g `RenderSystem extends BaseSystem<RenderComponent>` , ...

Comment: I don't think that solves the problem. The thing is, I want a list that can hold any type. Yes, I will pass in components (of type `Component` or `IComponent` (I use both a base class and an interface for components)), but different components implements different interfaces. E.g., I have a `RenderComponent` which inherits from `Component`, but it also implements `IRenderable`. The same for `PhysicsComponent` which inherits from `Component` and implements `IPhysics`. I need to have a list of `IRenderable` and `IPhysics`, so that I can use the specific methods (`Render()` and `PhysicsUpdate()`)

Comment: As @Duffydake mentioned, your system implementations will need to be declared as `class RenderSystem implements ISystem<RenderComponent>`.

Comment: Got it. Just tried Illyes Istvan's solution and it seems to work. Thanks.